# The RPC Srver Unavailable , while executing logman commands

Tags: networking, operating-system, performancecounter, perfmon, logman

im trying to run logman commands from the command line. crate counter is working fine, but for other commands like:-logman start datacollector , and logman stop datacollector , im getting a error as:- rpc server unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure the following services are runnning**
1.Windows event log
2.Remote procedure call(RPCSS)
3.DCOM server process launcher
4.RPC end point mapper  Automatic
5.Secure socket tunneling protocol(sstp)
6.Remote access auto connection manager
7.Remote connection manager

and set the start up type of the services to AUTOMATIC